# Firebase Hosting is not making calls to External APIS, which config should I add to Firebase.json to make this work?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, amazon-ec2, firebase-hosting

I'm building web app with flutter web and I'm using firebase hosting to serve the web app.
The web app makes an API post request to the static IP of my aws ec2 instance to get a response

```
const String api = 'http://7.91.300.2411:8080/predict';
 Map<String, String> upload = {'data1': _data1, 'data2': _data2};
var _body = jsonEncode(upload);
final Uri uri = Uri.parse(api);
http.Response response =
    await http.post(uri, headers: _headers, body: _body);
```

When I run the app on development, like on my local machine, it works, I see the logs on my ec2 server saying the endpoint was hit/called, and then it runs successfully.

But when I now deployed this web app to firebase hosting, the endpoint never gets hit/called, is as if the http post request was not made.

I've upgraded my firebase plan to blaze, yet it's still not working. I also enable cors on my ec2 instance.

Something I taught could solve the problem, was to edit the firebase.json file, and add some config to enable firebase hosting allow calls to external apis, but I don't know how to go about it

Comment: Egress traffic is only available for Blaze plans, and not in Spark plans. To enable calls to external APIs, you have to change the plan of your firebase project to the "Pay as you Go" one. You can do it from your project's dashboard, by clicking on the "Upgrade plan" link you find in the lower-left side of the page

Comment: @GregorioPalamà I said in my question that I changed my plan to Blaze plan and it is not still working

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Firebase Hosting does not make calls to external APIs. [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) "serves both static and dynamic content to a global CDN (content delivery network)". In the case of a Flutter web app, Firebase Hosting serves the files that were generated in the `/build/web` directory of your project when you [built the app for deployment](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/web#building-the-app-for-release) (aka the app release bundle).

The only scenario I can see that could be *considered* as Firebase Hosting making calls to external APIs is if you pair Firebase Hosting with Cloud Functions or Cloud Run, which, when they are executed, call the external API. Strictly speaking, in this scenario, Firebase Hosting does not call an API but serves dynamic content that was generated via a call to an API.

If I'm not mistaking, by looking at your code, we can conclude that this scenario does not apply to your case. In your case, Firebase Hosting just hosts your Flutter app release bundle.

In your case, you are using the Dart [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) in order to call the API **from your web page/app**. I don't see any reason why Firebase Hosting would prevent that: Your browser has downloaded the web page from Firebase Hosting and then the web page initiates, from your browser, a direct call to an API (without calling Firebase Hosting). So most probably the problem comes from something else.

Comment: Hey @OkaforZuruoke, did you have time to consider my answer?